# Is there a way to get cohort memberships for a particular User?

Tags: moodle-api

I want to pass a UserId and return all cohort memberships for that particular user. However, it doesn't seem that is possible.

I found this very old question on the moodle forums about the exact same thing: https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=319749

Am I missing the particular function to do this? Or is it not possible with the core api?

Scoured the docs, but can't see any way to do this with the core api.